# Using object notation as if it were an array - why does this evaluate?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the following evaluates to `3` instead of just declaring a syntax error when ran from a JavaScript REPL or through Chrome's Developer Tools:

```
{1, 2, 3};
3
```

As far as I can see, that *should* be a syntax error as demonstrated with:

```
var foo = {1, 2, 3};
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

I feel like there's just some quirky behaviour I'm not aware of?

Comment: "I feel like there's just some quirky behaviour I'm not aware of?" -> that's proof of actual understanding of Javascript !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the breakdown of the symbols:

- `{` Start code block
- `1` Number literal
- `,` Comma operator (evaluates both sides, returns right side)
- `2` Number literal
- `,` Comma operator
- `3` Number literal
- `}` End code block

Code blocks aren't restricted to defining `if`, `while` etc. blocks, they can be used anywhere. Therefore, your code is simply a block that contains a chained comma operator sequence, which returns the last item in the chain, hence `3`.

In the case of `var foo = {1, 2, 3};`, the `{` is indeed a "start object literal" symbol and not a "start code block" symbol.

**The same symbol can have multiple meanings based on context.**

Comment: It hit me when I got to your first bullet point, thanks :) Will accept once SO deems the correct amount of time has passed.